# How to use FTP via a proxy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, proxy, ftp

There is an FTP server that I can connect to on my development machine using FileZilla or the Rails app I'm working on. But as soon as I deploy the app to Heroku, the exact same connection parameters time out. My best guess is that the server blocks IP ranges that include Heroku, or dynamic IPs in general. It is not a configuration problem because the deployed app can connect to other FTP servers without issue.

To get around this problem, I'm trying to use a QuotaGuard static URL as a proxy, the add-on for which I've already provisioned and have an ENV variable for. The problem is that this static URL is in the form `http://username:password@subdomain.domain.com:9293`.

How can I use this to handle an FTP connection?

Current code (works locally, times out on Heroku):

```
Net::FTP.open(host, username, password) do |ftp|
    ftp.chdir(some_directory)
    # some logic here about which files to download
end
```

I've checked the Ruby docs for `Net::FTP` and `Net::HTTP` for more information. FTP only seems able to use a SOCKS proxy, but HTTP seems more flexible. Could I use the static URL as a SOCKS proxy by ignoring the `http://` prefix? Could I restructure the logic so that I can GET each FTP URL I need via HTTP?

I've also looked into using ProxyChainRB to do this but so far not having any luck since I'm running into the same issue of passing the proxy into an FTP connection.

Are there existing libraries that do this? Is there maybe a simpler solution I'm not seeing here?

Comment: What is that your doing that requires the use of FTP in the first place?

Comment: Synchronising a client's files. I know there are easier ways to do that but FTP is our only option here and there's a firewall somewhere preventing us from doing that which is why I'm trying to do it via a static IP outside of the blocked range.